# Is it possible to create enums with a variable which is defined only when using this enum?

Tags: java, object, methods, enums, constructor

I am trying to build an object which will be used to communicate with other objects. This communication object should have an enum, these enums include "ORDER_CREATED", "ORDER_CANCELLED" and "ORDER_AT_LOCATION". What I now want to do is assign a value to the enum "ORDER_AT_LOCATION" with a String location. This way there are no blank fields containing "null" if the enum is "ORDER_CREATED". 
I am not entirely sure if this is even possible.

I tried using a constructor for one specific enum but didn't have any luck

```
public class OrderEvent {
    private OrderEventTypes eventType;

}

enum OrderEventTypes{
    //I want a constructor with String info only for the enum ORDER_AT_LOCATION
    ORDER_AT_LOCATION{
        String info;
        public void ORDER_IN_TRANSIT(String info) {
            this.info = info;
        }

        public String getInfo() {
            return info;
        }
    }
    , ORDER_CANCELLED, ORDER_COMPLETED, ORDER_CREATED;


}
```

the expected result should be that this statement works.

```
if(eventType.equals("ORDER_AT_LOCATION")) {
    System.out.println(eventType.getInfo());
}
```

if you have any other nice solutions to this I would be very thankful, all the solutions I could come up with were perfectly do-able but not as nice as this would be.

Comment: `eventType.equals("ORDER_AT_LOCATION")` makes no sense. An instance of `OrderEventTypes` is never equal to an instance of `String`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create the `enum` with a constructor which accepts a `String` value and initialises the `info` field:

```
enum OrderEventTypes{

    ORDER_AT_LOCATION("ORDER_AT_LOCATION"),
    ORDER_CANCELLED,
    ORDER_COMPLETED,
    ORDER_CREATED;

    private final String info;

    OrderEventTypes(){
      this("");
    }

    OrderEventTypes(String info){
       this.info = info;
    }

    public String getInfo(){
       return this.info;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return this.info;
    }

}
```

Now when you need to compare, you can use the getter to get the value of the `info` field:

```
if("ORDER_AT_LOCATION".equals(eventType.getInfo())){
   System.out.println(eventType.getInfo());
}
```

Comment: Enum values are supposed to be constants: make `info` `final`, remove the setter, give it the value `""` in the no-arg ctor.

Comment: I got it working but had to tweak it a little by using a `setInfo(String info){...}` method and assigning the string value to the `eventType` after creating it.
I can't really use a constructor when setting the enum but it works regardless, so my problem is solved, thanks!

Comment: @CheapGucciClothing: are you actually using a mutable field in an `Enum`? If so, then you are certainly abusing it to do something that it's not meant to do. For example, you'll never be able to have to `ORDER_AT_LOCATION` values with different `info` values in them (because enums are by definition single-instance-per-value).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I think I'll go for another solution anyways, this would've been neat but you are right, my use case might not be something Enums should be used for.

Comment: Just use an [`EnumMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)…